# Is it possible to selectively deactivate alarms?

Tags: safety, boeing-737, airbus-a320, flight-instruments

My question is restricted to Airbus an Boeing's best sellers, namely the A320 and the B737. If relevant, answer can be extended to other types.

In those aircraft, there are multiple possible alarms (GPWS, stall warning, unwanted altitude excursion,...). Some alarms may be triggered by faulty sensors and deactivated. As an example, I can cite the "Too low! Gear!" of the [TK1951](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_Airlines_Flight_1951) due to faulty radio altimeter. When identifying an alarm is a false alarm, it should be nice to deactivate this alarm and only this alarm. My understanding is that you can mute an alarm when triggered but nothing prevent this alarm to be triggered again later in the flight, but I don't know if my understanding is right.

Is it possible (technically) to deactivate a specific alarm (let's say "Too low! gear!") for the rest of the flight after identifying this is a false alarm? In other word, is it possible to prevent a specific alarm from being triggered without impacting the other alarms?

**EDIT**: the main difference with the question [Can pilots turn off warning alarms? Re: Aeroperu Flight 603](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/58517/can-pilots-turn-off-warning-alarms-re-aeroperu-flight-603) is that I want to know if an alarm can be turned off for the remaining of the flight, not only ["whilst the condition exists."](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/58518/3394).

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, can someone reopen?